# Passing rapidjson::Object to a method

Tags: c++, rapidjson

Long story short: how can I pass a `rapidjson::Object` to a method?

Long story: I have the following code:

```
void CMyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    rapidjson::Document doc;
    doc.Parse(data.c_str(), data.size());

    std::string output{};
    for (const auto& obj : doc.GetObj())
    {
        if ("My_data" == obj.name)
        {
            ReadMyData(obj, output);
            continue;
        }
    }
}


void CMyClass::ReadMyData(???, std::string& output)
{
    //
}
```

I have tried:

```
// header
    template<bool Flag, typename T>
    void ReadMyData(const rapidjson::GenericObject<Flag, T>& obj, std::string& output);

// implementation
template<bool Flag, typename T>
void CMyClass::ReadMyData(const rapidjson::GenericObject<Flag, T>& obj, SWeather& output)
{

}
```

but I got:

```
.cpp(109): error C2672: 'CMyClass::ReadMyData': no matching overloaded function found
.cpp(109): error C2784: 'void CMyClass::ReadMyData(const rapidjson::GenericObject<Const,ValueT> &,std::string &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const rapidjson::GenericObject<Const,ValueT> &' from 'const rapidjson::GenericMember<Encoding,Allocator>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Encoding=rapidjson::UTF8<char>,
1>            Allocator=rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>
1>        ]
```

More info: `GetObj()`, is:

```
Object GetObj() { RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(IsObject()); return Object(*this); }
```

and `Object` is

```
template <typename Encoding, typename Allocator = RAPIDJSON_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR >
class GenericValue {
public:
    //! Name-value pair in an object.
    typedef GenericMember<Encoding, Allocator> Member;
    typedef Encoding EncodingType;                  //!< Encoding type from template parameter.
    typedef Allocator AllocatorType;                //!< Allocator type from template parameter.
    typedef typename Encoding::Ch Ch;               //!< Character type derived from Encoding.
    typedef GenericStringRef<Ch> StringRefType;     //!< Reference to a constant string
    typedef typename GenericMemberIterator<false,Encoding,Allocator>::Iterator MemberIterator;  //!< Member iterator for iterating in object.
    typedef typename GenericMemberIterator<true,Encoding,Allocator>::Iterator ConstMemberIterator;  //!< Constant member iterator for iterating in object.
    typedef GenericValue* ValueIterator;            //!< Value iterator for iterating in array.
    typedef const GenericValue* ConstValueIterator; //!< Constant value iterator for iterating in array.
    typedef GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator> ValueType;    //!< Value type of itself.
    typedef GenericArray<false, ValueType> Array;
    typedef GenericArray<true, ValueType> ConstArray;
    typedef GenericObject<false, ValueType> Object;
    typedef GenericObject<true, ValueType> ConstObject;
```

in `rapidjson` namespace.

Comment: `rapidjson::Value`?

Comment: Tried, outcome: `cannot convert argument 1 from 'const rapidjson::GenericMember<Encoding,Allocator>' to 'const rapidjson::Value &'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over an object returns a `GenericMember` not a `GenericObject`, you need:

```
for (const auto& member : doc.GetObj())
{
    if ("My_data" == member.name && member.value.IsObject())
    {
        ReadMyData(member.value.GetObject(), output);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Unless you need to be able to cope with other encodings you can change `ReadMyData` to not be a template and just take `rapidjson::Value::Object` as the obj parameter